# Submitting HTML values using VBA

Tags: vba

Using the `CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")` to extract information from a web-page, I've discovered that null response from `getElementsByTagName("table")` is experienced when a login is required on said web-page.

I've attempted to overcome this by using the following to set username/password for the login page:

```
oDom.getElementById("login-form-username").Value = strUser
oDom.getElementById("login-form-password").Value = strPwd
```

I've subsequently attempted to submit the information using:

```
oDom.getElementById("login-form-submit").Click
```

Unfortunately, the `.Click` does not seem to work. Is there anything else required to in order to submit the information? The `strUser` and `strPwd` values are input from `InputBox`.

Many thanks in advance

G

Comment: To interact with the page you would need a browser control like `webBrowser` or Selenium http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/topic-requests/6372

Comment: Ok thanks, I've got it working using:-

`CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")`

and using the above. I preferred the `CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")` method as this doesn't open the browser when parsing the page source.